# what is the meaning of model in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller

in MVC design pattern, we have three sections: model,view,controller. view and controller meaning are straight forward. but what is the meaning of model exactly? why model term??
in other hand, is this a correct approach to write database interaction functions in model?

Comment: This is more of a question easily answered by using your favorite search engine rather than an SO question. But what else would the view show than data that’s been modeled?

Comment: I'm searched before. but there are no exact answer.

Comment: I can’t find a single page that wouldn’t explain these three parts when I search for “MVC pattern”, they all explain what the parts are and how they relate quite clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the MVC pattern, the model holds the data and define the logic to manipulate your data.

Each view will read from the corresponding model in order to display the data in multiple ways.

There reason you need a model is because of separation of concerns. You can have one model that is your user list for example, and you can have two views that display this list according to some criteria. This way, if you need to change your views, you don't need to touch the model and its logic.

I recommend this [article](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html) on the evolution of the MVC pattern for more details.

Comment: thanks a lot. in asp.net mvc I do just define properties with get and set. and use them in controller. but in php we write functions that retrieve data from database in model. is that true that do same as asp.net mvc?

Comment: If you're using MVC architecture, you will use models. They can be objects with properties, and these can be stored on database (using ORM for example), or other methods. Please accept and vote for the answer if it answers your original question  ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers )